# Better way to display information from an ArrayList using a toString and Enhanced for loop

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist

I want to be able to display information from a contact list using an `ContactArrayList` of a `Contact` class.

I have an `ContactArrayList` class which holds a `Contact` class Objects. Inside the `ContactArrayList` class, I have an `add`, `remove`, `size`, `isEmpty`, etc,. methods for that class which will be used for that `ContactArrayList` in the `ContactArrayList` class along with other methods.

In my main/driver class, I have an object for the `ContactArrayList` class and created a "user" object and several "canned" objects of the `Contact` class.

#### My problem:

when the user chooses to display information for all contacts, including canned objects and the user object, I try using an enhanced for loop W/ a `toString` method of the `ContactArrayList` class, but because I am using an enhanced for loop using a `Contact` class "iterator" variable to go through and display information it's using the `Contact` `toString` when I want to use the `ContactArrayList` class `toString`.

#### `ContactArrayList`:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ContactArrayList 
{  
    ArrayList <Contact> contactArray = new ArrayList <Contact> ();

    String toStringM = " ";

    public Contact set(int index, Contact element)
    {    
         return contactArray.set(index, element);
    }

    public Boolean add(Contact element)
    {    
         return contactArray.add(element);
    }

    public Contact remove(int index)
    {    
         return contactArray.remove(index);
    }

    public int size()
    {    
         return contactArray.size();
    }

    public void clear()
    {    
          contactArray.clear();
    }

    public boolean isEmpty()
    {    

         return contactArray.isEmpty();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < contactArray.size(); i++)
        {
           toStringM = "Displaying all contacts and information: "
            + contactArray.get(i).getName() +
            contactArray.get(i).getLastName() +
            contactArray.get(i).getPhoneNumber()+
            contactArray.get(i).getEmailAddress();     
        }

      return toStringM;

    }

    public void sort()
    {
        ArrayList <Contact> tempSort = new ArrayList <> ();

        while(!contactArray.isEmpty())
        {
            int index = 0;
            for (int i = 1; i < contactArray.size(); i++)
            {
                if(contactArray.get(i).compareTo(contactArray.get(index)) == -1)
                 {
                    index = i; 
                 }
            }  

            tempSort.add(contactArray.get(index));

            contactArray.remove(index);
        }

        contactArray = tempSort; 
    }

    public void addContact(String passedString)
    {
        ArrayList <Contact> addContact = new ArrayList <Contact> ();

       for(Contact c : contactArray)
       {
          if (c.getName().indexOf(passedString) > -1)
          {
                  addContact.add(c);
          }
       }


    }

    public void searchAndRemove (String passedString)
    {          
       for(int i = 0; i < contactArray.size(); i++)
       {
          if (contactArray.get(i).getName().indexOf(passedString) > -1)
          {
                 contactArray.remove(i);
          }
       }

    }

}
```

#### `Main`:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HomeWork10 {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        userInput();
    }

    public static void userInput()
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        ContactArrayList   cal1 = new ContactArrayList ();
        Contact c1 = new Contact(); //User Input Object

        //"Canned" refernce Objects
        Contact c2 = new Contact("James", "Conney", "7608949843",
                                 "jamesConney@seeMe.com");
        Contact c3 = new Contact("JJ", "Jim", "7608939836",
                                 "theStuff@gmail.com");
        Contact c4 = new Contact("Jimmer", "ConBoy", "7608040500", 
                                 "jimConBoy@seeMe.com");
        //Adding canned objects to the ArrayList
        cal1.add(c2);
        cal1.add(c3);
        cal1.add(c4);

        String name = " ";
        String lastName = " ";
        String phoneNumber = " ";
        String emailAddress = " ";
        String yesOrNo = " ";
        int userInput = 0;
        boolean userContinues = true;

        do
        {
            System.out.println("Please enter 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5 for the following"
                               + " options"); 
            System.out.println("1. Add a new Contact, 2. display all contacts, "
                              + "3. search for a contact and remove them,"
                              + " 4. Sort the Contact LIST by name, 5. Quit: ");
            userInput = in.nextInt();
            in.nextLine();
            switch(userInput)
            {

                case 1: 

                        System.out.println("Please enter the new contact info"
                                 + "(Name, lastName, phoneNumber and emailAddress): ");
                       name = in.nextLine();
                       lastName = in.nextLine();
                       phoneNumber = in.nextLine();
                       emailAddress = in.nextLine();

                       c1 = new Contact(name, lastName, phoneNumber, emailAddress);
                       cal1.add(c1); 
                       break;
                case 2:

                    System.out.println(cal1.toString());
                    break; 

                case 3: 
                    System.out.println("Enter a contact to search for and remove: ");

                    name = in.nextLine();                
                    cal1.searchAndRemove(name);
                    break;

                case 4:   
                    System.out.println("Sorting the contact list by name "
                                       + "and displaying it to the screen.");
                    cal1.sort();
                    System.out.println(cal1.toString());


                    break;

                case 5: 
                    System.out.println("Goodbye");
                    System.exit(0);
                       break;

                default:
                    System.out.println("Invalid entry, try again.");

                    break;
           }

                System.out.println("Would you like to continue ? (Y/N): ");
                yesOrNo = in.next();

                if(yesOrNo.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"))
                {
                    System.out.println("");
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("Goodbye");
                    userContinues = false;
                }


        }while(userContinues);



    }

}
```

#### `Contact`:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Contact implements Comparable
{

    private static String name = " ";

    private static String lastName = " ";
    private static String phoneNumber = " ";
    private static String emailAddress = " ";

    public Contact()
    {
        //Default constructor
    }

    public Contact(String passedName, String passedLastName, 
                   String passedPhoneNumber, String passedEmailAddress)
    {
        this.name = passedName;
        this.lastName = passedLastName;
        this.phoneNumber = passedPhoneNumber;
        this.emailAddress = passedEmailAddress;
    }

    //Setter Methods
    public void setName(String passedName)
    {
        this.name = passedName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String passedLastName)
    {
         this.lastName = passedLastName;
    }
    public void setPhoneNumber(String passedPhoneNumber)
    {
        this.phoneNumber = passedPhoneNumber;
    }
    public void setEmailAddress(String passedEmailAddress)
    {
        this.emailAddress = passedEmailAddress;
    }
    //Getter Methods

    public String getName()
    {
        return this.name;
    }
    public String getLastName()
    {
        return this.lastName;
    }
    public String getPhoneNumber()
    {
        return this.phoneNumber;
    }
    public String getEmailAddress()
    {
        return this.emailAddress;
    }
    //Methods

    public String toString()
    {
        return "Name, Last name, phone number, and email in order: " 
             + this.name +" " + this.lastName + " " + this.phoneNumber + 
             " " + this.emailAddress;
    }


    public int compareTo(Object other)
    {
        Contact passedContact = (Contact) other;
        if(this.lastName.compareTo(passedContact.lastName) == 0)
        {
             return this.name.compareTo(passedContact.name);
        }
        else
        {
            return this.lastName.compareTo(passedContact.lastName);
        }

    }

    public static String userInput()
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter your name, last name,"
                           + " phone number, and email address: ");
        Contact.name = in.nextLine();
        Contact.lastName = in.nextLine();
        Contact.phoneNumber= in.nextLine();
        Contact.emailAddress = in.nextLine();

        Contact newContact = new Contact(name, lastName, phoneNumber, emailAddress);

        return newContact.getName() + newContact.getLastName() +
               newContact.getPhoneNumber() + newContact.getEmailAddress();

    }

     public boolean equals(Object anObject)
    {
    //equals method which trys to check if the object to be ,ade is legdible
        if (anObject == null || getClass() != anObject.getClass())
        {
            return false ;
        }
        Contact otherContact = (Contact) anObject ;

        return (this.name.equals(otherContact.getName())) &&
                this.lastName.equals(otherContact.getLastName()) &&
                this.phoneNumber.equals(otherContact.getPhoneNumber()) &&
                this.emailAddress.equals(otherContact.getEmailAddress());
    }         
}
```

#### Output:

> ```
> Please enter 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5 for the following options
> 1. Add a new Contact, 2. display all contacts, 3. search for a contact and remove them, 4. Sort the Contact LIST by name, 5. Quit: 
>
> 1
> Please enter the new contact info(Name, lastName, phoneNumber and emailAddress): 
> Mike
>
> Dim
>
> 123456789
>
> email
>
> Would you like to continue ? (Y/N): 
> y
>
> Please enter 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5 for the following options
>
> 1. Add a new Contact, 2. display all contacts, 3. search for a contact and remove them, 4. Sort the Contact LIST by name, 5. Quit: 
>
> 2
> Name, Last name, phone number, and email in order: Mike Dim 123456789 email
>
> Name, Last name, phone number, and email in order: Mike Dim 123456789 email
>
> Name, Last name, phone number, and email in order: Mike Dim 123456789 email
>
> Name, Last name, phone number, and email in order: Mike Dim 123456789 email
>
> Would you like to continue ? (Y/N):
> ```

*Overall, Im going to keep trouble shooting this issue, its probably something simple, but would like someone to point out the obvious. If you need anymore information about the ContactArrayList class, or Contact class or Main/driver class let me know!*

Comment: Could you please show the full code for `ArrayList` class?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem.. I think there is some important code missing.. Do you want to add the rest of your `Main`? And maybe `Contact` too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for providing the missing classes.
The problem lies in your `Contact` class:

```
private static String name = " ";
private static String lastName = " ";
private static String phoneNumber = " ";
private static String emailAddress = " ";
```

Those variables are all `static`, meaning that they don't exist once per `Contact`, but once per Application. So all `Contact`s will share the same `name`, `lastName`, etc..

If you remove the `static` modifier, it should work.

But you have a few other problems in your code which I want to address:

1. Don't call your `ContactArrayList` like that. Other developers will look at it and expect it to extend an `ArrayList`, which it doesn't. Simply call it `Contacts`, which is much nicer (I will call it so form here on out).
2. You should not use `toString` to display user readable text. It is meant to output text for debugging purposes. Replace your `toString` methods with the following:

   1. `Contact`:

      ```
      public String toReadableString() {
          return "Name: " + this.name + " " + this.lastName + ", phone number: " + phoneNumber + ", email: " + this.emailAddress;
      }
      ```
   2. Don't call your `ArrayList<Contact>` `contactArray`. It is not an array. Call it something like `members`..
   3. `Contacts` -> your `toString` method was broken. You just stored the result from each `Contact` in the same `toStringM` (also a bad name. I have no idea what that is supposed to mean)

      ```
          public String toReadableString()
          {
              String result = "Displaying all contacts and information:";
              for (Contact contact : members) {
                  result += "\n\t" + contact.toReadableString();
              }
              return result;
          }
      ```
   4. Your `addContact(String passedString)` method is broken. I don't know what it should do, but it only creates a new `ArrayList` with which you never do anything.
   5. Please replace `.indexOf(passedString) > -1` with `.contains(passedString)`. It may do the same thing, but one is much easier to read.
   6. I am not quite sure what the method `public static String userInput()` in `Contact` is supposed to do. It looks like you can just get rid of it.
   7. Your inheritance for `Contact extends Comparable` is wrong. It should be `Contact extends Comparable<Contact>`
   8. Your `compareTo` method doesn't work right. Replace it with the following:

      ```
      @Override
      public int compareTo(Contact other) {
          if (this.lastName.compareTo(other.lastName) == 0) {
              return this.name.compareTo(other.name);
          } else {
              return this.lastName.compareTo(other.lastName);
          }
      }
      ```
   9. Replace your `sort` method with `Collections.sort(members);` (which you can do, because `Contact` is a proper `Comparable<Contact>` now)

Comment: Okay, thanks man i really appreciate all the help! i see, in the future all look to give better descriptive names. As far as the addContact method, its supposed to be "adding" a Contact object to the "members" of the contact list. I will follow up with the other changes as well!

Answer (score 1):

The `toString()` method is java is meant to produce `Strings` for developers to debug. I would suggest either implementing your own `toReadableString()`, or to simply define how you want to render it on the spot. Java 8 has some nice functions to do so:

```
case 2:
    String s = contacts.stream()
            .map(c -> Stream.of(c.getName(), c.getLastName(), c.getPhoneNumber(), c.getEmailAddress())
                    .collect(Collectors.joining(", ")))
            .collect(Collectors.joining("\n\t", "Displaying all contacts and information:\n\t", ""));
    System.out.println(s);
    break;
```

First we create a `Stream` from `contacts`. We then transform the `Stream` of `Contact`s into a `Stream` of `String`s with `map`. Again we create a `Stream` of the four values and join them with `,`. This second `Stream` will create each Contact.

We then come back to the outer `Stream`, where we now have a `Stream` of readable contacts. We join them too, separating them with `"\n\t"`, thus creating a `String` that looks like the following:

```
Displaying all contacts and information:
    Mike, Dim, 123456789, email
    Foo, Bar, 987654321, hello@wor.ld
```

Comment: I see and like the approach, but I am still in a "beginners" class, so a lot of the methods you're using I am unfamiliar with and I couldn't use it anyway since I cant use anything we hadn't been taught yet. Id love to try that out though and see how it works anway. Thank you!

Comment: @EOxJ I didn't know you were doing an assignment!

Comment: @EOxJ I suspect the error lies within your `ArrayList` class. Can you show us that code?

Comment: Yea, but I will come across what you showed soon hopefully :)

Comment: Posted it in the post

Comment: @EOxJ I can't reproduce the problem. Please post the rest of `Main` and `Contact`

Comment: Okay Ill put it in the post, and thanks for helping format the posts

Comment: I put it in the post!

Comment: yep! Thank you for all the help! I do still have an issue with the original "Canned" objects, when use the sort method, and sort them, it sorts the "user" entered objects alphabetically, but not the original canned objects that were in the arraylist to begin with. the problem is in my sort() method in the ContacArrayList class up above in the posts.

Comment: @EOxJ I added some additional fixes to my other answer

Answer (score 0):

You are already looping in `toString` method of ArrayList. So shouldn't you must do

```
cal1.toString();
```

instead of

```
for(Contact display : cal1.contactArray)
{
    System.out.println(display.toString());
}
```

Comment: So, that works right, but it only displays the user entered object like before  and not the canned objects, and if I loop through it again and try and add another user object it "erases" the last one entered.

Comment: You loop is looking fine to me. I think the problem might be in the method of adding contacts to list. Can you post your method `add`?

Comment: Okay! I will add it to the post

Comment: @EOxJ I am unable to find any error in mentioned code that might produce the unexpected results. There must be some other code dealing with your list. Might be your other switch cases.

Comment: it wasnt in the switch cases, but in the toString for my ContactArrayList class, thanks for helping out man!